# Name of Simple Logical System

Tags: logic, terminology, first-order-logic

There's a logical system, devised by someone whose name escapes me, that consists of two moves. You begin with one line, then draw another line, and somehow this can be built to capture all sorts of logical phenomena. Can anyone recall the name of this logic or its inventor?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like George Spencer-Brown's [*Laws of form*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_Form).

Comment: This is exactly it! Thanks so much!